# Angularjs bind data to span text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have following span that I am using as a text input.

```
<span ng-model="sampleText" style="width:100px; padding:20px, 100px;" class="TextBox"></span>
```

Reason why I am using span instead of "input" or "textarea" is so that I have one box which can keep adding rows as I hit enter.  This is more elegant way than showing a big box of textarea. 
But problem I am facing is how do i bind the text that has been entered to the ng-model.
Maybe using ng-init?
Please let me know how to bind the text that has been entered to the "sampleText" 
Thanks

Comment: You can write a custom directive to interact with `ngModel`, but something easier might be to write or use one that auto-expands a standard textarea, like https://github.com/monospaced/angular-elastic

Comment: You can use `input` element and still add new rows as user hits "enter" key - why complicating things? Just clear content of that input after that.

Comment: I tried with input didn't work. Searched online not much luck. Do you have some example to look at?

Answer (score 0):

The `ngModel` directive itself doesn't do much. It provides a controller that is used by other directives, like `input` (yes, `input` is a directive). That means you have to write your own one.

But you are lucky, because the [documentation for the ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) has an example that's almost identical to yours.